# Jquery child>Parent>child>child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with my following code:

**Html:**

```
<table>
 <tr class="oc">
   <td class="process">process</td>
   <td><input name="data" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="oc">
   <td class="process">process</td>
   <td><input name="data" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

On click of **td[class=process]** , I need the value of **input[name=data]**. I tried in several ways and failed. I attempts include follows:

**Inside Jquery on click function:**

```
var v = $(this).parent().children(":eq(2)").children().val()*1;
var v = $(this).parent().children.children("input[name=data]").val()*1;
var v = $(this).parent().find("input[name=data]").val()*1;
var v = $(this).parent().children(":eq(2)").children().val()*1;
```

What happening is, every time I click the **td[class=process]**, I am getting the previous value of **input[name=data]** + current value of **input[name=data]**

And, I have no idea why. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `$(this).next().find('input[name=data]').val()`

Comment: Don't use multiplication operator to convert value into number. It's not a good practice. Use `parseFloat(number)` or `parseInt(number, 10)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your third variant already works.

```
var v = $(this).parent().find("input[name=data]").val()*1;
```

Your 2nd approach is incorrect, as `children` is a function.

Your 1st and 4th approach (unless I'm blind) are the same. However, since `:eq()` is zero-indexed; the `<td>` you're selecting is actually position `1`, not `2`. You can see this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cN6GS/).

```
var v = $(this).parent().children(":eq(1)").children().val()*1;
```

---

You may also like to hear about `next()`, which might make this a bit easier.

```
var v = $(this).next().children().val() * 1;
```

See [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next), and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cN6GS/1/).

Answer (score 2):

using jquery it is very simple

```
$('.process').click(function(e)
{
    var myData = $(this).next().children().val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am messing up somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to target the next column and then [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to access the input inside it.

```
$("td.process").click(function(){
  var v = $(this).next("td").find("input[name='data']").val();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(this).next().find('input[name=data]').val()
```